# How to call virtual functions from statically allocated objects?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

Let's say I have a base class 'A' and two classes 'B' and 'C', which are derived from the base class 'A'

I know I can do this

```
A *a = new B();
or
A *a = new C();
a->handle() //handle is a virtual function in A. class B and C overloaded this function and added its own implementation.
```

Then it will call the handle function from either B or C object.

But, I have a restriction that I cannot use a pointer in my program. I have to define A as

```
A a //not A *a
```

Then how do I implement this so that it calls the handle function from class B or C?

Comment: Is this too obvious: (&a)->handle(); ? - have I missed something?

Comment: @John3136: That does the same thing as `a.handle();`. The OP wants to call `B::handle()` with an A object.

Comment: All good - I figured I must have misread something!

Comment: My answer below fixes this scope problem by making the appropriate non-virtual call directly with the type specifer.

Comment: This is the way not to ask a programming question: "_I can not use a pointer in my program_" **You need to explain your requirements.** "I cannot use is xxx" is useless. My answer would be: use pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You cannot take a value of type `A` and pretend it's a `B`. That's just bad, and cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Odd question.  It can't. Not by any sane means.  It's an 'A' afterall.

Assuming you know 'I want to call C's virt' you could do disturbing things like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A { public: virtual int foo() { return 1; } };
class B : public A{ public: virtual int foo() { return 2; } };
class C : public A{ public: virtual int foo() { return 3; } };

int main()
{
    A a;
    C *c = (C*)&a;
    int x = c->C::foo();  // EXAMPLE 1
    printf("x == %d\n", x);

    x = ((C&)a).C::foo(); // EXAMPLE 2

    printf("x == %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that example 2 is just the same thing without anything in the middle. Harder to read, but same result.

The key is using C::foo();  Without C:: you will go through the virtual table and the result will be '1'.

Comment: I'm going to add a comment to my post and say: Don't do this.  I don't like it when people say 'you can't do that', as almost everything is possible in C/C++.  But I'm a big supporter of 'I really don't think you should do this.'.  In the end, only you know why you do or don't need to though.

Comment: "_I don't like it when people say 'you can't do that', as almost everything is possible in C/C++._" But **the question is the canonical absurd programming question**, a subset of absurd engineering questions: "I want to do X, the proper way to do X is Y, but I cannot use Y". It's like asking "how can I run without moving my feet". It's inane.

Answer (score 0):

If this is homework, then perhaps professor meant to use references (&) instead of pure pointers (*).

```
A &a = * new B();
or
A &a = * new C();
a.handle()
```

Though the references in C++ are pretty much the same thing as regular pointers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but its not a homework and can not use a reference as well as you mentioned the reference is just the same as regular pointers. I have this restriction because of a compiler I am using to generate a reverse code..

Comment: Well, then I would say it is impossible. You have to use some kind of a pointers to refer to the right Virtual Function table.

Comment: See my answer below.  Example 2 won't even require you to use a temporary pointer of the derived type.

Comment: @Joe, a good point! I would say that your answer is probably the closest one (depending on how the question should be interpreted). Though, I would be really cautious to call foo() as a virtual function in your example (at least the usage of it), because call decision is made at the compile-time, not run-time. But maybe that is exactly what the author of this question wanted to hear... Anyway +1 from me for creativity ;)